# Datetime parsed incorrectly by read_csv of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following CSV file:

```
date,time
8/23/2018,12:08:50
8/23/2018,12:08:59
8/23/2018,12:09:59
8/23/2018,12:10:59
8/23/2018,12:11:59
```

I load this file into pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=False, parse_dates=[['date','time']])
```

However, `df["date_time"].head()` shows wrong dates:

```
0   2018-03-04 20:59:19
1   2018-03-04 21:00:19
2   2018-03-04 21:01:19
3   2018-03-04 21:02:19
4   2018-03-04 21:03:19
```

Why does it happen?

UDPATE:

CSV file contains commas. Therefore I use comma separator by default.

Comment: Please notice that I just didn't insert "," in the example of CSV file. Sorry, about it. I do not have issues with the separators. All values are loaded correctly, except date and time.

Comment: Such a problem is highly unlikely. I suspect you're looking at one file and loading another.

Comment: Also, you're not providing all the information. You show `df["date_time"]` but `df` has no column called `date_time`.

Comment: @IanS. Hey, before downvoting, please investigate what `parse_dates=[['date','time']]` is doing. It creates the column `date_time` automatically!

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a csv file. That looks like fixed width file. Notice that there's no comma (or any other character) separating the `date` and `time` columns.

Try pandas [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) instead.

E.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('/path/to/file', colspec=[(0,10), (11,18)])
```

Alternatively you can specify that the csv is separated by whitespace, not a comma or pipe, by using `sep='\s{1,2}'` when you call `read_csv`.

Comment: Please see my comment below the thread. I do not have issue with the separator, because it's ",". Sorry, it was unclear in the question.